# How do I delete rows if the cells contain the current month?

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl

If a cell contains the current month, delete the row.

E.g in excel sheet, Before: 

03/11/2021  row1    row11 
25/10/2021  row2    row22 
30/10/2021  row3    row33 
02/11/2021  row4    row44 
30/10/2021  row5    row55 
01/11/2021  row6    row66 
30/10/2021  row7    row77

After: 

25/10/2021  row2    row22 
30/10/2021  row3    row33 
30/10/2021  row5    row55 
30/10/2021  row7    row77

I tried this script:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import date

wb = load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
x = ws.max_row
y = ws.max_column

current_month=date.today().month

for r in range(1, x+1):
    for j in range(1, y+1):
        d=ws.cell(row=x+1-r,column=j)
        if d.is_date and d.value.date() == current.month:
             ws.delete_rows(x+1-r)
             break

wb.save("file2.xlsx")
```

But nothing happens.
If I change to `if d.is_date and d.value.date() != current.month:`, all rows are deleted.
Where do I have to correct?

Comment: Which column is the date in?

Comment: The first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume that the date doesn't "equal" to its month. So you should probably do:

```
if d.is_date and d.value.date().month == current.month:
    ...
```

Comment: Also, work from the bottom of the sheet up.